# rspec how query html body email with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd, actionmailer

Maybe it's newbie question but I'm stucked.
I try to query html email with capybara with no luck.
here is the spec

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "spec_helper"
require "resque"
require "resque_spec"

describe 'MailerUtils in action'  do
  include MailerMacros

  let(:service_provider_email) { FactoryGirl.create(:service_provider_email) }
  let(:service_provider) { service_provider_email.service_provider }
  let(:service_provider_email_list) { service_provider_email.service_provider_email_list   }

  before :all do
    Resque.inline = true
  end

  describe 'send one marketing email and unsubscribe' do
    before :each do
      reset_email
      PromotionActions.perform :too_low_profile_score, service_provider.id
    end

    it "should have unsubscribe link" do
      last_email.body.should have_content("отписаться от рассылки")
    end

    it "should have correct city in link" do
      last_email.body.find(:xpath, "//a[@id=\"unsubscribe_link\"][@href=\"http://#{service_provider.city.name}.#{service_provider.country.domain}/#{service_provider.code}?uncheck=marketing]")
      end
    end
  end
```

last example fail. how can I query html from email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Capybara.string(last_email.body).find(...)
```

Comment: I find details in sources # Wraps the given string, which should contain an HTML document or fragment
    # in a {Capybara::Node::Simple} which exposes all {Capybara::Node::Matchers} and
    # {Capybara::Node::Finders}. This allows you to query any string containing
    # HTML in the exact same way you would query the current document in a Capybara
    # session. For example:
    #
    # node = Capybara.string <<-HTML
    # <ul>
    # <li id="home">Home</li>
    # <li id="projects">Projects</li>
    # </ul>
    # HTML
    #
    # node.find('#projects').text # => 'Projects'

Comment: Minor correction: `Capybara.string(last_email.body.encoded).find(...)`